# Can http client cancel the reuqest before whole body is received?

Tags: sockets, http

For example,
By an user, a client send GET request for a 1GB size of data, then the client is receiving the data.
But the user decides to cancel previous one and download another data.
At this moment, does the client immediately cancel previous HTTP request before 1GB size of whole data and send a new HTTP GET request with reusing socket?
Because I'd like to avoid TCP slow start by new socket connection in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to signal canceling of the request inside a HTTP connection, i.e. while keeping the connection open. This means the only way is to close the underlying TCP connection and create a new one and send the new request using the new connection.

Answer (score 0):

Although Steffen Ullrich is correct and although you cannot stop a response midway (barring an impolite disconnection), you could use the HEAD request to review the metadata (i.e. size of the download) prior to submitting the GET request.